# Transforming Java Stream API toMap with merging to Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, java-stream

I nead to transform this Java code to elegant Kotlin code. The goal is to group JSON arrays (io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray) by last element, and if column values in group is different then concatenate to String separated by semicolon and then return list of result JSON arrays. I've tried something like:

```
  list.groupingBy { it.getInteger(it.size() - 1) }
      .reduceTo...
```

Java code:

```
   List<JsonArray> list = Arrays.asList(new JsonArray("USD", 337301456, "a", 1),
                                        new JsonArray("USD", 337301456, "b", 1),
                                        new JsonArray("USD", 337301456, "c", 1),
                                        new JsonArray("EUR", 337301456, "a", 2),
                                        new JsonArray("EUR", 337301456, "b", 2)
                                        );

    List<JsonArray> result =
            new ArrayList<>(
                    list.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(arr -> arr.getValue(arr.size() - 1),
                                    arr -> arr,
                                    (a1, a2) -> {
                                        JsonArray newArr = new JsonArray();
                                        for (int i = 0; i < a2.size() - 1; i++) {
                                            Object e1 = a1.getValue(i);
                                            Object e2 = a2.getValue(i);
                                            if (e1 == null)
                                                newArr.addNull();
                                            else if (e2 != null && !e2.equals(e1))
                                                    newArr.add(e1.toString() + ";" + e2.toString());
                                                 else newArr.add(e1);
                                        }
                                        return newArr;
                                    })).values());

    result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
["USD",337301456,"a;b;c"]
["EUR",337301456,"a;b"]
```

Comment: Your Java code does not compile unfortunately, can you make sure this is running?

Comment: I've refreshed it once again @Yassin Hajaj. It works for me.

Comment: `JsonArray(...)` is not the way we instantiate objects in Java

Comment: if `e1==null` then `e2` is abandoned regardless of its value. Are you sure this is intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct translation will be:

```kotlin
val result = list
    .groupingBy { it.getValue(it.size() - 1) }
    .reduce { _, a1, a2 ->
        val newArr = JsonArray()
        for (i in 0 until a2.size() - 1) {
            val e1 = a1.getValue(i)
            val e2 = a2.getValue(i)
            if (e1 == null)
                newArr.addNull()
            else if (e2 != null && e2 != e1)
                newArr.add("$e1;$e2")
            else
                newArr.add(e1)
        }
        newArr
    }.values
```